# Type inference rules in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, types, switch-statement

I read the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#var-declarations-in-case-expressions) MSDN page, which states the following interesting thing:

> The first rule is that the var declaration follows the normal type
> inference rules: The type is inferred to be the static type of the
> switch expression. From that rule, the type always matches.

Nowhere in MSDN could I find a reference to the so-called "normal type inference rules", and why does `var` used in that sense infer to the static type of the switch expression?

Perhaps I don't know what a `static` type is. I know what the `static` keyword does, but I don't think that's what's happening in the switch expression.

Comment: Can you share small code sample with your problem?

Comment: Static type is just referring to a type known at compile time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is a statically typed language, meaning that types must be known at compile-time, and the type assigned to a variable cannot change at runtime. Consider first that all of the following lines result in exactly the same thing:

```
int x = 123;
System.Int32 x = 123;
var x = 123;
```

- `int` is just an alias for `System.Int32`
- The compiler *infers* that `x` is of type `System.Int32` when using `var` because it's been assigned an integral number.

What you **can't** do with C# that you can do in **dynamically** typed languages (like javaScript) is this:

```
var x = 123;
x = "Hello world";
```

In C# the compiler will complain that you cannot assign a string to an int variable, but JavaScript, being a dynamic language will allow it.

Comment: Since OP asked about the switch case it might be good to add that in the switch case if you use it in pattern matching it infers the type of whatever entered the switch.

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps I don't know what a `static` type is. I know what the `static` keyword does, but I don't think that's what's happening in the switch expression.

In the example that you have linked, by "*static type of the switch expression*" they are referring to the type of the variable `shapeDescription` - e.g. type **string**.

In other words, following "*normal type inference rules*" - the `var o` also has type **string**.

```cs
static object CreateShape(string shapeDescription)
{
    switch (shapeDescription)
    {
        // removed for conciness

        case var o when (o?.Trim().Length ?? 0) == 0:
            // white space
            return null;
    }
}
```